# .htaccess File Placement

Tags: .htaccess, hosting

Can a subdirectory have its own .htaccess file that is different from the .htaccess file in the root directory?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a clean URL only in a subfolder of my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955519/how-can-i-use-a-clean-url-only-in-a-subfolder-of-my-website)

Answer (score 1):

Every directory can have its own `.htaccess`, and the file in all parents up to the document root are parsed when making a request for a physical file.

Comment: Thanks... what does "parsed" mean?

Comment: In this case it means "read and processed".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This a convenient (depending on your situation) way of making only certain directories have limit user access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a .htaccess file in subdirectories.  However you may need to change the allowoverride option in the base .htaccess or httpd.conf file to allow certain options to be overridden.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride for details